# bootstrap row more columns and overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have made my own bootstrap col like that

```
.col-lg-8th{
    width:12.5%;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(181,181,181);
}
```

and also have some bigger cols like
    .col-lg-8th3{
        width:37.5%;
    }

How can I realize this row

```
 <div class="row calendarrow">
            <div class="col-lg-8th">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8th">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8th">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8th">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8th">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8th">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8th5">
            </div>
        </div>
```

with the last col having a width of 62.5% but not being put into the next row but just cut off after 100%?

Thanks

Comment: Could you reformulate or precise your question? I really don't understand what you want.

Comment: I can't find any class col-lg-8th in the bootstrap documentation. Are you sure these even exists ? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: I want to know, if there is the possibility to have more that 12 columns in a bootstrap row (e.g. 3,3,4,3) with the last one being cut after the 12 is reached and hidden, just like overflow:hidden

I made the 8th myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/ocqpsvvc/8/

```
.col-lg-8th{
    width:12.5%;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(181,181,181);
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.col-lg-8th5{
    width:62.5%;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(181,181,181);
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.calendarrow{white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;}
```